# SPServices getListItems CAMLQuery Issue

Tags: jquery, caml-query, spservices

Attempting to retrieve items from a list where field School_id is equal to a school_id javascript variable, and using SPServices GetListItems operation.

If I run the script without the CAMLQuery: Parameter, it returns all items on the list which is great, however when I add the Query to filter my returns I get

```
POST [server Address redacted] 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I assume there's something wrong with my Query, I've already tried removing the  tags but yields same result.

Is it possible that it actually is a server side error despite it successfully returning data with the Query absent?

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var school_id = getQueryVariable("school_id");  

  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Contacts",
    CAMLViewFields:  "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='FirstName' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><eq><FieldRef Name='school_x0020_id'/><Value Type='Text'>" + "4440" + "</Value> </eq> </Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + ", " + $(this).attr("ows_FirstName") + "</li>";
        $("#ContactsUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>

<ul id="ContactsUL"/>
```

Comment: next time use CamlJs to help you write the caml query for sharepoint, they have an amazing Chrome addin as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Query

```
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='school_x0020_id'/><Value Type='Text'>4440</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
```

Comment: Thanks. After changing the casing in fieldref to match as well as it works now.

Comment: I would have also checked your CAMLViewFields.  `<FieldRef Name='School_x0020_id' />` is not in there.  And in the above answer, it would need `School_x0020_id` (capital letter), not what is above (which has a lowercase letter).

Comment: how to fetch the calculated column from the splist in sp services? it it possible to fetch it and assign it o a string variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your

```
<eq>  </eq>
```

tags to

```
<Eq> </Eq>
```

I think case matters for those tags.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things,

- `eq` should be `Eq`
- is school id the name of your column? Make sure the casing is correct.
- Lookup values should be represented like:

  `<Eq>
   <FieldRef Name='RelatedIssues' LookupId='True' />
   <Value Type='Lookup'>4440</Value>
  </Eq>`

Also look at the [Biwug CAML Designer](http://www.biwug.be/resources) for all your CAML querying needs.